# Close Button On Top of Thick Div Border

Tags: css, html

I have a div with a very thick border and I'd like to have the close button on the top-right of the border and not the div.  The problem I'm having is that no matter what z-index I put, the border is always on top of my close-button div.  I've tried setting the border to be on the inside of the div, but the same problem keeps happening.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
.aboutcontainer{
    position: relative;
    width: 55%;
    height: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 6%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 3;
    border: 20px solid black;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    overflow: auto;

    box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 2px black, 0px 5px 5px #333333;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 2px black, 0px 5px 5px #333333;
    -khtml-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 2px black, 0px 5px 5px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 2px black, 0px 5px 5px #333333;
}

.closeBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    z-index: 4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: hi it's work now check http://tinkerbin.com/3WJ6Yfs0

Answer (score 0):

Your `overflow: auto;` tag is hiding everything outside of the main `div`, including things atop the border. Remove it, and the button will show.

Comment: I need the `overlow: auto;` for the scroll bar when the text is bigger than the div.  I also have:
`.bgcontainer{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8);
 z-index: 2;
 display: none;
}`

which is the background div.  So it goes:
`<div class="bgcontainger">
<div class="aboutcontainer">
<div class="closeBtn">
</div>
</div>
</div>`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:auto` and even `z-index` is not necessary here. Give `width` and `height` to inner div to see the effect.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nVnLk/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove border from .aboutcontainer.
Put it inside another **div** and give that parent container some padding and background color that will create a border effect.
Place your **.aboutcontainer** and **.closeBtn** inside that div now you are free to position the close button anywhere you want also keeping the overflow property of your .aboutContainer intact.